# Alternative way for Background Process

Tags: c#

I've created a simple application in C# which purpose is to have a Windows Service running on Background in the whole time the computer is alive and which I know is a non-GUI process.

I want the Service to execute some command like, programmatically lock the computer, send data to one of my Windows Form Application, show Windows Form Application etc. which will not work because it is Windows Service. I found it really hard for me to work with this.

Now, my question is, is there any alternative way for what I want to achieve?

I mean other solution for running background process in the whole time and do the GUI job?

I am really out of ideas, anyone can suggest/help will be very appreciated!

Comment: Use a Tray-Application instead?

Comment: I don't understand why I have a vote down, I ask for help, and I get a vote down. :-/

Comment: @lokusking - I'll try your suggestion, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always write a winforms application that will run a background thread listening for commands and executing tasks. Then all you need to do is register this executable to be started when a session is started. The application could be minimized to the tray so that the user could still manipulate it.